# How to display node/add/sometype form on another page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

The whole problem is following:

Lets say we have Items, Items can have Bids, Items can have Questions and Question can have Answer.

When an Item is displayed, all content associated with this Item should also be displayed. Additionally depending on roles, certain forms to make Bids, ask Questions and replay Answers should be display.

How to achieve this? Should I have separate node type for each type? Or should I treat some subtypes like Questions and Answers as comments? Should I use some well-known modules for this?

I am using Drupal 7 and I tried to write a custom module but I didn't get it working properly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To get a node edit form, you need to include [node.pages.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.pages.inc/6).

```
<?php
  // required for Drupal 6
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages'); 
  // which nodeform you want
  $node_type = 'YOURNODETYPE';
  $form_id = $node_type . '_node_form';
  // maybe add current users info
  global $user;
  // create a blank node
  $node = array(
    'uid' => $user->uid,
    'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''),
    'type' => $node_type,
  );
  // Invoke hook_nodapi and hook_node
  node_object_prepare($node);
  // Or you can also use an exiting node, for example
  // $node = node_load(123);
  // and the display the form:
  $output = drupal_get_form($form_id, $node);
?>
```

Comment: "create a blank node" section isn't working for drupal 7, but I found a solution for that. thanks

Comment: The code above is wrong for d7. As said @user462645 below, the $node variable has to be an object  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
  $node_type = 'yournodetype';
  $form_id = $node_type . '_node_form';

  global $user;

  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->uid = $user->uid;
  $node->name = (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : '');
  $node->type = $node_type;
  $node->language = '';

  node_object_prepare($node);

  return drupal_get_form($form_id, $node);

Comment: @**user506259** what is your soulution?

Comment: this method return me  error in drupal 7,but `Marius Ilie` solution work correctly.

Comment: to get dobeerman's example to work in d7, add 'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE and cast the $node array into an object. i.e.:

Comment: @dobeerman Can you answer this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497392/attach-or-embed-node-add-form-with-a-view)

Answer (score 35):

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');

$form = node_add('nodetype');
$output = drupal_render($form);
```

If your node form has a file upload widget, you should add the following lines to the menu array:

```
'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'node'),
'file' => 'node.pages.inc',
```

Comment: Can you add an example on how to "add following lines to the menu array"?

Comment: function yourmodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $node_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'node');
  $items['system/ajax']['file path'] = $node_path;
  $items['system/ajax']['file'] = 'node.pages.inc';
}

Comment: thank you your answer helped me a lot :D `about file upload widget`

Comment: @MariusIlie I am new to drupal so were do I put this code. I have tried it in hook_node_view in this hook I have add the $output like this $node->content['article'] = $output; but nothing happen. So after render how to attach it to the node view?

Comment: It is good to add this line in your code
if (!function_exists('node_add')) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
}

Comment: Hi, This answer worked for me very well, but I'm working with profile2 and instead render the node-type, I'm rendering that kind of form which I can't make it work with the exactly file_path like this one :

`'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'node'),`

Which should be the file_path for that kind of form, can I pass the id of form?

Comment: @MariusIlie Can you answer this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497392/attach-or-embed-node-add-form-with-a-view)

Answer (score 5):

```
// Drupal 7    
// Embed node creation form on a custom page inside module.
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$form = node_add('node_machine_name'); 
return drupal_render($form);
```

Comment: Works perfectly on Drupal7! Thx

Comment: just copied my answer :|

Answer (score 4):

The Module [Form Block](http://drupal.org/project/formblock) is the easiest way to embed a node form on a page. Then I would use views with a block display and an argument to show a tabular listing of these related nodes.

Although the Drupal 7 comment module is built on fields it really isn't quite flexible enough for non comment like things. If you want your sub-type to have a title and body then comments is probably the way to go. If you only want custom fields then a node is the way to go and possibly using something like [Automatic Nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle).

Update for 2014: If adding a block without coding is preferred by anyone you may wish to check out [Advanced Form Block](https://drupal.org/project/afb) module, which adds a few features to your standard blocks (you can add as many as you like, make them all submit via AJAX and even select which fields you want). Unlike the Form Block module it is still actively maintained for Drupal 7.

Comment: Can you answer this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497392/attach-or-embed-node-add-form-with-a-view)

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 7 the blank node needs to be created as an object (not an array).

```
  $node->uid = $user->uid;
  $node->name = (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : '');
  $node->type = $node_type;
  $node->language = '';
```

Answer (score 2):

Thomas's answer looks good to me: Formblocks and perhaps automatic nodetitles.  I think you could expand on that with [Nodereference URL Widget](http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url) -- using nodereferences rather than comments, and letting that module do the work of keeping child-nodes connected to their parent.

Answer (score 1):

To get dobeerman's example (the accepted answer) to work in d7, add 'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE and cast the $node array into an object. i.e.:

```
$node = (object)array(
  'uid' => $user->uid,
  'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''),
  'type' => $node_type,
  'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE
);
```

Comment: Can you answer this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497392/attach-or-embed-node-add-form-with-a-view)

Answer (score 1):

I am reproducing the solution which worked for me on my case. it is available as an answer on Drupal.org and it may help others with the same problem I was experiencing.

The answer is available here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1336212#comment-6192404.

I am copying-pasting it below:

in your custom callback OR in a hook_form_alter, call either...

```
<?php
form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
?>
```

...OR...

```
<?php
form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'user', 'user.pages');
?>
```

...depending on whether the core Drupal form you're loading is a node form or a user form.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the problem:

In my hook_menu

```
$items['add-visiteur'] = array(
  'title' => 'Add',
  'page callback' => 'add_visiteur',
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

and my callback function

```
function add_visiteur() {
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages'); 
  // which nodeform you want
  $node_type = 'visiteur';
  $form_id = $node_type . '_node_form';
  // maybe add current users info
  global $user;
  // create a blank node
  $node = new stdClass;
  $node->uid = $user->uid;
  $node->name = (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : '');
  $node->type = $node_type;

  // Invoke hook_nodapi and hook_node
  node_object_prepare($node);

  $output = drupal_get_form($form_id, $node);
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: Can you answer this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497392/attach-or-embed-node-add-form-with-a-view)