# How to call a node in a hook menu?

Tags: drupal, menu, drupal-7

I hope you can help me because I don't know how to call a node in a hook_menu in Drupal 7.

Is it possible ?

```
$items['basketfacile/planning'] = array(
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
        'title' => 'Test',
        'description' => "description",
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('basketfacile_plannings_form'),
        'access arguments' => array('access content')
    );
```

This is my item menu who call a form, but I want to call a node form which allready exists in my Drupal installation. We can take Article for example.

Have you an idea ?

Comment: May I ask you WHY you need to do this ? 
You can either copy the existing $items[node/add/%] array to your custom menu hook, or even easier alias the node/add/X path with basketfacile/planning. that way, you have actual permission use instead of access content permission.. 
If you want to alter the form, use form_alters.

Comment: May be a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344754/drupal-7-how-to-display-node-add-sometype-form-on-another-page

Comment: Thanks for your help but I found how to do what I wanted. See my answer

Comment: thanks. very helpful and straight forward :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, it's very easy to embed a node in an other page you can do that :

```
$items['menu/submenu'] = array(
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
        'title' => 'YOUR_TITLE',
        'description' => "YOUR_DESCRIPTION",
         'page callback' => 'node_add',
        'page arguments' => array('YOUR_NODE_TYPE_NAME_MACHINE'),
        'access callback' => 'node_access',
        'access arguments' => array('create', 'YOUR_NODE_TYPE_NAME_MACHINE'),
        'file' => 'node.pages.inc',
        'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'node')
);
```