# Drupal 7 node add form ajax not working

Tags: drupal-7

I am using drupal 7, i am embedding a node add form using the solution provided here: [Drupal 7 - How to display node/add/sometype form on another page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344754/drupal-7-how-to-display-node-add-sometype-form-on-another-page) (using node_add('content_type') )

The form displays fine, but there is one problem, the "add another item" button does not work fine, i can see the ajax request being sent but it wont return anything and there is no error, i am banging me head over this for past 2 hours now, but cant find a solution about it.

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Same problem here. Would love to see an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

Alter your node form and include the following line in its form constructor:

```
form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
```