# Drupal 7.31 - Problems with file type field of node

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have created some custom page on frontend for particular type of node modyfications. Here's my page callback:

```
function vintranet_talk_edit_entry_page_callback($sNid) {
    module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');

    $oNode = node_load($sNid);

    return drupal_get_form('page_node_form', $oNode);
}
```

My node has one field with file attachments.

Config:

```
'vintranet_talk_attachments' => array(
    'field_name'     => 'vintranet_talk_attachments',
    'label'          => t('Attachments'),
    'type'           => 'file',
    'cardinality'    => -1,
),
```

Instance:

```
'vintranet_talk_attachments' => array(
    'field_name'     => 'vintranet_talk_attachments',
    'label'          => t('Attachments'),
    'entity_type'    => 'node',
    'bundle'         => 'intranet_talk_page',
    'widget'         => array(
        'type' => 'file_mfw',
    ),
    'settings'       => array(
        'max_filesize'       => 10,
        'file_directory'     => 'intranet/talk',
        'file_extensions'    => 'jpg, png, gif, pdf, zip, doc, rtf, xdoc, rar',
        'description_field'  => 1,
    ),
    'display'        => array(
        'default' => array(
            'type' => 'file_table',
        ),
    ),
),
```

My first problem is, when I want to upload JPG file after module installation, system sends me this message:
[image]

So ok... I'm going to check that particular field settings in Structure and I see this:

[image]

Why the hell it is saved like this?!

Okaaaaay.... so I'm changing this form field value on `jpg, png, gif, pdf, zip, doc, rtf, xdoc, rar`, saving and trying to upload the image one more time...

[image]

....clickin "Upload" button.... aaaaandd....

[image]

....yup.... that's my 2nd problem :/. Have no idea why it's not working. On the backend, in other hand, the "Upload" button works perfectly. Am I missing something?

(working on Drupal 7.31 version)

Menu node add path:

```
array(
  'mynode/add/path' => array(
            'title'              => 'Title - new entry',
            'page callback'      => 'vintranet_talk_add_entry_page_callback',
            'file'               => 'vintranet_talk.pages.inc',
            'access arguments'   => array('vintranet_talk_add_entry'),
        ),
);
```

Comment: take a look at the second answer by 'Marius Ilie' on this stack question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344754/drupal-7-how-to-display-node-add-sometype-form-on-another-page

Comment: @2pha Ok, but I have `file` key in this particular menu path (updated question on the end). If I will change `file`, page will crush :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for my problems:

```
function hook_menu_alter(&$aItems) {
    $sNodePath = drupal_get_path('module', 'node');

    $aItems['file/ajax']['file path']    = $sNodePath;
    $aItems['file/ajax']['file']         = 'node.pages.inc';
    $aItems['system/ajax']['file path']  = $sNodePath;
    $aItems['system/ajax']['file']       = 'node.pages.inc';
}
```

Comment: glad you got it sorted :)