# Attach or embed node add form with a view

Tags: ajax, forms, drupal, drupal-7

I am using Drupal 7.54. I want to attach or embed a node add form to a view so that when a user submits the form, the view below the form will be updated in realtime via ajax. The form will be shown above the view. My view block name is **Statuses Stream**.

I tried [Form block](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock) module and putting the form in the header section of my view using views ui, but after submit, it was redirecting to the node created page.

Then I tried [Advanced Form Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/afb) module. I created a form using AFB module. The form name is **Statuses**. It is submitting the form with ajax, but it is not updating the view in the realtime. I have to refresh the page manually to show the created node below the form.

I am open to any solution programmatically or through a module.

Note: For those who know, I am trying to mimic the [statuses module](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses). It does exactly what I am looking for. The problem began when I came to know that it is not an entity. So now I am trying to make the same functionality with Content type.

Comment: I think that is better if you write your question in https://drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer posted https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238447/attach-or-embed-node-add-form-to-a-view

Answer (score -1):

You could use something like [Views Refresh](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_refresh) to manually update the view below instead of refreshing the page.